# Waiting time display app　in Python

Tags: python

This application is for restaurant patrons to know how long they have to wait in line.
We would like to design a more sophisticated GUI interface, but do not know how to go about it.
Please let me know if there are any appropriate libraries or other resources.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as message
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


wait_que=[]
list_four_table=[]
list_two_table=[]
list_one_table=[]
list_four_table_situ = []
list_two_table_situ = []
list_one_table_situ = []
four_table=[]
two_table=[]
one_table=[]


enpty = 0 # Vacant Seat
pre_oreder = 1 # Occupied, but not yet order
post_order = 2 # Ordered but dish has not yet come
post_dish = 3  # Already dish arrived 

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        br = tk.Button(self, text = "Show Waiting Time", command = self.show_screen_br, width=28)
        bo = tk.Button(self, text = "Check Seat Situation", command = self.show_screen_bo, width=28)
        bs = tk.Button(self, text = "Register Number of Seats", command = self.show_screen_bs, width=28)
        bc = tk.Button(self, text = "Change Seat Situation", command = self.show_screen_bc,width=28)
        ba = tk.Button(self, text = "Add Waiting Queue", command = self.show_screen_ba, width=28)

        bs.pack(padx =10, pady = 10)
        bo.pack(padx =10, pady = 10)
        bc.pack(padx =10, pady = 10)
        ba.pack(padx =10, pady = 10)
        br.pack(padx =10, pady = 10)

    # "Show Waiting Time" Screen
    def show_screen_br(self):
        global screen_br
        global entry_br
        screen_br = tk.Toplevel()
        screen_br.title("Show Waiting Time")
        screen_br.geometry('300x150')

    # if there is no queue
        if wait_que == []:
            label_wait_num = tk.Label(screen_br, text = 'How many are you')
            b_close = tk.Button(screen_br, text = "Close", command = self.quit_window_br)
            entry_br = tk.Entry(screen_br, font=("Helvetica", 24))
            b_result = tk.Button(screen_br, text = "Show Waiting Time", command = self.show_wait_time)

            label_wait_num.pack()
            b_close.pack(side = "bottom")
            entry_br.pack()
            b_result.pack()
    # if there is any queue
        else:
            label_wait_num = tk.Label(screen_br, text = 'What number are you in line for?')
            b_close = tk.Button(screen_br, text = "Close", command = self.quit_window_br)
            entry_br = tk.Entry(screen_br, font=("Helvetica", 24))
            b_result = tk.Button(screen_br, text = "Show Waiting Time", command = self.show_wait_time)

            label_wait_num.pack()
            b_close.pack(side = "bottom")
            entry_br.pack()
            b_result.pack()

    # "Check Seat Situation" Screen
    def show_screen_bo(self):
        global screen_bo
        global four_table
        global two_table
        global one_table
        screen_bo = tk.Toplevel()
        screen_bo.title("Check Seat Situation")
        screen_bo.geometry('735x500')

        bo_close = tk.Button(screen_bo, text = "Close", command = self.quit_window_bo)

        # Seats for 4 persons
        if four_table==[]:
            message.showinfo("Caution","Seats for 4 perons are not registerd. Please register from 'Register Number of Seats' on Home Screen")
        else:
            tbl_four = ttk.Treeview(screen_bo)
            tbl_four['columns'] = ('number', 'four_situation')
            tbl_four['show'] = 'headings'
            tbl_four.heading('number', text = 'Seat Number')
            tbl_four.heading('four_situation', text = 'Situation')

            tbl_four.column('number'  , width=100)
            tbl_four.column('four_situation' , width=100)

            for i in range(four_table):
                table_num = str(list_four_table[i])
                tbl_four.insert('', 'end', values=(table_num,jp_dic_four_table[table_num]))

            tbl_four.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)

        # Seats for 2 persons
        if two_table==[]:
            message.showinfo("Caution","Seats for 2 perons are not registerd. Please register from 'Register Number of Seats' on Home Screen")
        else:
            tbl_two = ttk.Treeview(screen_bo)
            tbl_two['columns'] = ('number', 'two_situation')
            tbl_two['show'] = 'headings'
            tbl_two.heading('number', text = 'Seat Number')
            tbl_two.heading('two_situation', text = 'Situation')

            tbl_two.column('number'  , width=100)
            tbl_two.column('two_situation' , width=100)

            for i in range(two_table):
                table_num = str(list_two_table[i])
                tbl_two.insert('', 'end', values=(table_num,jp_dic_two_table[table_num]))

            tbl_two.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)

        # Seats for 1 person
        if one_table==[]:
            message.showinfo("Caution","Seats for 1 peron are not registerd. Please register from 'Register Number of Seats' on Home Screen")
        else:
            tbl_one = ttk.Treeview(screen_bo)
            tbl_one['columns'] = ('number', 'one_situation')
            tbl_one['show'] = 'headings'
            tbl_one.heading('number', text = 'Seat Number')
            tbl_one.heading('one_situation', text = 'Situation')

            tbl_one.column('number'  , width=100)
            tbl_one.column('one_situation' , width=100)

            for i in range(one_table):
                table_num = str(list_one_table[i])
                tbl_one.insert('', 'end', values=(table_num,jp_dic_one_table[table_num]))

            tbl_one.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 20)

        bo_close.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)
    
    
    # "Register Number of Seats" Screen
    def show_screen_bs(self):
        global screen_bs
        global entry_four_table
        global entry_two_table
        global entry_one_table
        screen_bs = tk.Toplevel()
        screen_bs.title("Register Number of Seats")
        screen_bs.geometry('735x300')

        b_close = tk.Button(screen_bs, text = "Close", command = self.quit_window_bs)
        label_four_table = tk.Label(screen_bs, text = 'Tell me how many seats you have for 4 persons')
        label_two_table = tk.Label(screen_bs, text = 'Tell me how many seats you have for 2 persons')
        label_one_table = tk.Label(screen_bs, text = 'Tell me how many seats you have for 1 persons')
        entry_four_table = tk.Entry(screen_bs, font=("Helvetica", 24))
        entry_two_table = tk.Entry(screen_bs, font=("Helvetica", 24))
        entry_one_table = tk.Entry(screen_bs, font=("Helvetica", 24))
        b_seat = tk.Button(screen_bs, text = "Register Seats", command = self.situ)

        b_close.pack(side = "bottom")
        label_four_table.pack()
        entry_four_table.pack()
        label_two_table.pack()
        entry_two_table.pack()
        label_one_table.pack()
        entry_one_table.pack()
        b_seat.pack()


    # "Change Seat Situation" Screen
    def show_screen_bc(self):
        global screen_bc
        global entry_table_type
        global entry_table_num
        global entry_table_situ
        global four_table
        global two_table
        global one_table
        screen_bc = tk.Toplevel()
        screen_bc.title("Change Seat Situation")
        screen_bc.geometry('600x700')
    
        b_close = tk.Button(screen_bc, text = "Close", command = self.quit_window_bc,)
        label_table_type = tk.Label(screen_bc, text = 'Which type of seats you will change. Type in 4 or 2 or 1')
        label_table_num = tk.Label(screen_bc, text = 'What is the number of the seat. Type in number only')
        label_table_situ = tk.Label(screen_bc, text = 'What is the situation of the seat.（Vacant：0、Waiting Order：1、Waiting Dish：2、Dish Arrived：3）')
        entry_table_type = tk.Entry(screen_bc, font=("Helvetica", 24), width = 5)
        entry_table_num = tk.Entry(screen_bc, font=("Helvetica", 24), width = 5)
        combobox_table_situ = ttk.Combobox(screen_bc, values=(0, 1, 2, 3), font=("Helvetica", 24) , state="readonly")
        b_situ = tk.Button(screen_bc, text = "Change Seat Situation", command = self.change_situ)
        label_exp_1 = tk.Label(screen_bc, text = "Seat for ")
        label_exp_2 = tk.Label(screen_bc, text = 'No.')
        label_exp_3 = tk.Label(screen_bc, text = 'Change to')

        b_close.pack(side = "bottom")
        label_table_type.pack()
        label_exp_1.pack()
        entry_table_type.pack()
        label_table_num.pack()
        label_exp_2.pack()
        entry_table_num.pack()
        label_table_situ.pack()
        label_exp_3.pack()
        combobox_table_situ.pack()
        b_situ.pack(pady=20)
    
        #Seats for 4 perosons
        if four_table==[]:
            message.showinfo("Caution","Seats for 4 perons are not registerd")
        else:
            tbl_four = ttk.Treeview(screen_bc)
            tbl_four['columns'] = ('number', 'four_situation')
            tbl_four['show'] = 'headings'
            tbl_four.heading('number', text = 'Seat Number')
            tbl_four.heading('four_situation', text = 'Situation')

            tbl_four.column('number'  , width=100)
            tbl_four.column('four_situation' , width=100)

        
            for i in range(four_table):
                table_num = str(list_four_table[i])
                tbl_four.insert('', 'end', values=(table_num,jp_dic_four_table[table_num]))
            
            tbl_four.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 20, pady=20)

        #Seats for 2 perosons
        if two_table==[]:
            message.showinfo("Caution","Seats for 2 perons are not registerd")
        else:
            tbl_two = ttk.Treeview(screen_bc)
            tbl_two['columns'] = ('number', 'two_situation')
            tbl_two['show'] = 'headings'
            tbl_two.heading('number', text = 'Seat Number')
            tbl_two.heading('two_situation', text = 'Situation')

            tbl_two.column('number'  , width=100)
            tbl_two.column('two_situation' , width=100)

            for i in range(two_table):
                table_num = str(list_two_table[i])
                tbl_two.insert('', 'end', values=(table_num,jp_dic_two_table[table_num]))

            tbl_two.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 20, pady=20)

        #Seats for 1 peroson
        if one_table==[]:
            message.showinfo("Caution","Seats for 1 peron are not registerd")
        else:
            tbl_one = ttk.Treeview(screen_bc)
            tbl_one['columns'] = ('number', 'one_situation')
            tbl_one['show'] = 'headings'
            tbl_one.heading('number', text = 'Seat Number')
            tbl_one.heading('one_situation', text = 'Situation')

            tbl_one.column('number'  , width=100)
            tbl_one.column('one_situation' , width=100)

            for i in range(one_table):
                table_num = str(list_one_table[i])
                tbl_one.insert('', 'end', values=(table_num,jp_dic_one_table[table_num])) 
        
            tbl_one.pack(side = tk.LEFT, padx = 20, pady=20)

    # "Add Waiting Queue" Screen
    def show_screen_ba(self):
        global screen_ba
        global entry_add_que
        screen_ba = tk.Toplevel()
        screen_ba.title("Add Waiting Queue")
        screen_ba.geometry('300x150')

        b_close = tk.Button(screen_ba, text = "Close", command = self.quit_window_ba)
        label_add_que = tk.Label(screen_ba, text = 'How many of the customer just queued')
        entry_add_que = tk.Entry(screen_ba, font=("Helvetica", 24))
        b_que = tk.Button(screen_ba, text = "Add Waiting Que", command = self.add_que)
        label_que = tk.Label(screen_ba, text = "Current queue is"+str(wait_que)+".")

        b_close.pack(side = "bottom")
        label_add_que.pack()
        entry_add_que.pack()
        b_que.pack()
        label_que.pack(pady=10)

    def quit_window_br(self):
        global screen_br
        screen_br.destroy()

    def quit_window_bo(self):
        global screen_bo
        screen_bo.destroy()

    def quit_window_bs(self):
        global screen_bs
        screen_bs.destroy()

    def quit_window_bc(self):
        global screen_bc
        screen_bc.destroy()

    def quit_window_ba(self):
        global screen_ba
        screen_ba.destroy()
    

    def situ(self):
        self.all_situ_table()

    def change_situ(self):
        self.change_table_situ()

    def add_que(self):
        self.add_wait_que()


    # Name each seats
    def name_four_table(self): 
        global list_four_table
        global four_table
        try:
            four_table = int(entry_four_table.get())
            for i in range(four_table):
                factor_four_table = ''
                four_table_mod = factor_four_table.replace('','4P Seats No'+str(i+1))
                list_four_table.append(four_table_mod)
        except ValueError:
            message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
        except:
            message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Try again")

    def name_two_table(self): 
        global list_two_table
        global two_table
        try:
            two_table = int(entry_two_table.get())
            for i in range(two_table):
                factor_two_table = ''
                two_table_mod = factor_two_table.replace('','2P Seats No'+str(i+1))
                list_two_table.append(two_table_mod)
        except ValueError:
            message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
        except:
            message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Try again")


    def name_one_table(self): 
        global list_one_table
        global one_table
        try:
            one_table = int(entry_one_table.get())
            for i in range(one_table):
                factor_one_table = ''
                one_table_mod = factor_one_table.replace('','1P Seats No'+str(i+1))
                list_one_table.append(one_table_mod)
        except ValueError:
            message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
        except:
            message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Try again")
        

    # Make dictionary to match seat name and seat situation
    def situ_four_table(self):
        global list_four_table_situ
        global list_four_table
        global dic_four_table
        global jp_dic_four_table
        global time_dic_four_table
        self.name_four_table()
        for i in range(four_table):
            factor_four_table = ''
            four_table_mod = factor_four_table.replace('',str(0))
            list_four_table_situ.append(four_table_mod)
        dic_four_table = dict(zip(list_four_table, list_four_table_situ))
        # Dictionary to show seat status in words
        jp_dic_four_table = dic_four_table.copy() 
        time_dic_four_table = dic_four_table.copy()
        for i in jp_dic_four_table:
            jp_dic_four_table[i] = 'Vacant'

    def situ_two_table(self):
        global list_two_table_situ
        global list_two_table
        global dic_two_table
        global jp_dic_two_table
        global time_dic_two_table
        self.name_two_table()
        for i in range(two_table):
            factor_two_table = ''
            two_table_mod = factor_two_table.replace('',str(0))
            list_two_table_situ.append(two_table_mod)
        dic_two_table = dict(zip(list_two_table, list_two_table_situ))
        jp_dic_two_table = dic_two_table.copy()
        time_dic_two_table = dic_two_table.copy()
        for i in jp_dic_two_table:
            jp_dic_two_table[i] = 'Vacant' 

    def situ_one_table(self): 
        global list_one_table_situ
        global list_one_table
        global dic_one_table
        global jp_dic_one_table
        global time_dic_one_table
        self.name_one_table()
        for i in range(one_table):
            factor_one_table = ''
            one_table_mod = factor_one_table.replace('',str(0))
            list_one_table_situ.append(one_table_mod)
        dic_one_table = dict(zip(list_one_table, list_one_table_situ))
        jp_dic_one_table = dic_one_table.copy()
        time_dic_one_table = dic_one_table.copy()
        for i in jp_dic_one_table:
            jp_dic_one_table[i] = 'Vacant'

    # Assign names and create dictionaries 
    def all_situ_table(self):
        self.situ_four_table()
        self.situ_two_table()
        self.situ_one_table()
        message.showinfo("Registration Success","Seat data has been successfully registered")
        self.quit_window_bs()

    # Change seat situation
    def change_table_situ(self): 
        global dic_four_table
        global dic_two_table
        global dic_one_table
        global jp_dic_four_table
        global jp_dic_two_table
        global jp_dic_one_table
        if list_four_table == [] and list_two_table == [] and list_one_table == []:
            message.showerror("Error","Type in seat number from 'Register Number of Seats' on Home Screen")
            self.quit_window_bc()
        else:
            try:
                table_type = int(entry_table_type.get())
                table_num = int(entry_table_num.get())-1
                table_situ = int(entry_table_situ.get())
                if table_type == 4:
                    table_name=list_four_table[table_num]
                    try:
                        dic_four_table[table_name] = str(table_situ)
                        message.showinfo("Change Success","Seat situation has been successfully changed")
                        for i in jp_dic_four_table:
                            if jp_dic_four_table[i] == "0":
                                jp_dic_four_table[i] = "Vacant"
                            elif jp_dic_four_table[i] == "1":
                                jp_dic_four_table[i] = "Wait for order"
                            elif jp_dic_four_table[i] == "2":
                                jp_dic_four_table[i] = "Wait for dish serve"
                            elif jp_dic_four_table[i] == "3":
                                jp_dic_four_table[i] = "Dish served"
                        self.quit_window_bc()
                    except ValueError:
                        message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
                    except:
                        message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Make sure that seat really exists and try again")  
                elif table_type == 2:
                    try:
                        table_name=list_two_table[table_num]
                        dic_two_table[table_name] = str(table_situ)
                        message.showinfo("Change Success","Seat situation has been successfully changed")
                        for i in jp_dic_two_table:
                            if jp_dic_two_table[i] == "0":
                                jp_dic_two_table[i] = "Vacant"
                            elif jp_dic_two_table[i] == "1":
                                jp_dic_two_table[i] = "Wait for order"
                            elif jp_dic_two_table[i] == "2":
                                jp_dic_two_table[i] = "Wait for dish serve"
                            elif jp_dic_two_table[i] == "3":
                                jp_dic_two_table[i] = "Dish served"
                        self.quit_window_bc()
                    except ValueError:
                        message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
                    except:
                        message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Make sure that seat really exists and try again") 
                elif table_type == 1:
                    try:
                        table_name=list_one_table[table_num]
                        dic_one_table[table_name] = str(table_situ)
                        message.showinfo("Change Success","Seat situation has been successfully changed")
                        for i in jp_dic_one_table:
                            if jp_dic_one_table[i] == "0":
                                jp_dic_one_table[i] = "Vacant"
                            elif jp_dic_one_table[i] == "1":
                                jp_dic_one_table[i] = "Wait for order"
                            elif jp_dic_one_table[i] == "2":
                                jp_dic_one_table[i] = "Wait for dish serve"
                            elif jp_dic_one_table[i] == "3":
                                jp_dic_one_table[i] = "Dish served"
                        self.quit_window_bc()
                    except ValueError:
                        message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
                    except:
                        message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Make sure that seat really exists and try again") 
                    else:
                        message.showerror("Error",'Please type in 4 or 2 or 1')
            except ValueError:
                message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
            except:
                message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Make sure that seat really exists and try again")        

    # Add custumer to the queue
    def add_wait_que(self):
        global wait_que
        global add_que
        try: 
            add_que =int(entry_add_que.get())
            if add_que <=4:
                wait_que.append(add_que)
                message.showinfo("Registration Success", "Data has been successfully registered.")
                self.quit_window_ba()
            else:
                message.showerror("Error","If there are more than 5 people, divide them into two groups, so that each group has no more than 4 people.")
                self.add_wait_que()
        except ValueError:
            message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
        except:
            message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Make sure that seat really exists and try again")      

    # if there is no que, will use this function
    def add_table_wait_time(self):
        global time_dic_four_table
        global time_dic_two_table
        global time_dic_one_table
        for i in dic_one_table:
            if dic_one_table[i] == "0":
                time_dic_one_table[i] = str(0)
            elif dic_one_table[i] == "1":
                time_dic_one_table[i] = str(50)
            elif dic_one_table[i] == "2":
                time_dic_one_table[i] = str(40)
            elif dic_one_table[i] == "3":
                time_dic_one_table[i] = str(15)
        for i in dic_two_table:
            if dic_two_table[i] == "0":
                time_dic_two_table[i] = str(0)
            elif dic_two_table[i] == "1":
                time_dic_two_table[i] = str(50)
            elif dic_two_table[i] == "2":
                time_dic_two_table[i] = str(40)
            elif dic_two_table[i] == "3":
                time_dic_two_table[i] = str(15)
        for i in dic_four_table:
            if dic_four_table[i] == "0":
                time_dic_four_table[i] = str(0)
            elif dic_four_table[i] == "1":
                time_dic_four_table[i] = str(50)
            elif dic_four_table[i] == "2":
                time_dic_four_table[i] = str(40)
            elif dic_four_table[i] == "3":
                time_dic_four_table[i] = str(15)
    
    # Show waiting time
    def show_wait_time(self):
        global screen_br
        try:
            wait_num = int(entry_br.get())
            self.add_table_wait_time()
            if wait_que == []:
                if wait_num == 1:
                    message.showinfo("Waiting Time", 'Your waiting time is'+min(time_dic_one_table.values())+'minutes')
                elif wait_num == 2:
                    message.showinfo("Waiting Time", 'Your waiting time is'+min(time_dic_two_table.values())+'minutes')
                elif wait_num == 3 or wait_num == 4:
                    message.showinfo("Waiting Time", 'Your waiting time is'+min(time_dic_four_table.values())+'minutes')
                self.quit_window_br()
            else: #If there is a queue
                if wait_que[wait_num-1] == 1:
                    for i in range(wait_num-1):
                        if wait_que[i] == 1:
                            table_key = min(time_dic_one_table)
                            time_dic_one_table[table_key] = str(int(time_dic_one_table[table_key]) + 50)
                    messege.showinfo("Waiting Time", 'Your waiting time is'+min(time_dic_one_table.values())+'minutes')
                elif wait_que[wait_num-1] == 2:
                    for i in range(wait_num-1):
                        if wait_que[i] == 2:
                            table_key = min(time_dic_two_table)
                            time_dic_two_table[table_key] = str(int(time_dic_two_table[table_key]) + 50)
                    message.showinfo("Waiting Time", 'Your waiting time is'+min(time_dic_two_table.values())+'minutes')
                elif wait_que[wait_num-1] == 3 or wait_que[wait_num-1] == 4:
                    for i in range(wait_num-1):
                        if wait_que[i] == 3 or wait_que[i] == 4:
                            table_key = min(time_dic_four_table)
                            time_dic_four_table[table_key] = str(int(time_dic_four_table[table_key]) + 50)
                    message.showinfo("Waiting Time", 'Your waiting time is'+min(time_dic_four_table.values())+'minutes')
                self.quit_window_br()
        except ValueError:
            message.showerror("Error","Can't change to integer. Try again")
        except:
            message.showerror("Error","Unexpected Error. Make sure that seat really exists and try again") 
            
root = tk.Tk()
f = MainFrame(root)
f.pack()
f.mainloop()
```

I'm new to programming and not a native English speaker so this may sound weird, but I appreciate your advice!

Comment: You code too complicated to review. It also mixes UI and Business logic. It also uses globals. Watch this https://youtu.be/eHhXoCNCI1c?si=943IW4DFV6-EFguC and try applying MVP pattern mentioned in the video. The presenter also uses TKinter so should be a good fit.